# HERE maps - are not up to date, how can I update them?

Tags: android, here-api, android-sdk-2.3

I tried working with here maps, but unfortunately the maps are not up-to-date, 
many routs I tried to navigate to, it navigated me wrongly, example:

going through a street on the opposite directions

while google maps are updated correctly

how can I fix this kind of issues ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here-api is not the correct place to post these concerns. The conversations are limited to the actual API from Here, rather than the map data. This is a concern for Here rather than a technical discussion.

Regardless, if you find some incorrect map data, feel free to report it here:

https://mapcreator.here.com